# Channel Entry with Matrix clone or duplicate

Tags: channel-entries, matrix

Does anybody have an idea of a plugin that can clone/duplicate channel entries that use the Matrix plugin? I have found MX Cloner (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner) however this is not compatible with Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ. We recently updated Matrix to version 2.5.6 (on EE 2.6.1), and MX Cloner 1.2.1 stopped working. They may update it, but until they do, Devot-ee''s information appears to be accurate.

Comment: Well, just tested it again (EE 2.7.3, MX Cloner 1.2.1, Matrix 2.5.10, CartThrob 2.5, Products channel with a matrix variations field of 13 columns and 7 rows, and about 45 fields in all) - works perfectly here.  Me and my staff have used it extensively over the prior 6 months without issue.  Doesn't mean there is no issue at all of course, just maybe that it is not a general one.

Answer (score 0):

The devotee information is wrong in this case - I just tested mxcloner with a complex entry with a big matrix inside of it and it cloned it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a very large site that is heavily reliant on the Matrix extension: EE 2.7.2, MX Cloner 1.2.7, and Matrix 2.6.

Haven't had any issues with that particular combination.